# One-syllable word/adjective for 'receives little attention'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to find a one-syllable adjective that means 'receives little attention' / 'receives less attention'.

For example, the sentence 'Paralympics usually receives less attention than the Olympics.' can be paraphrased as:

> 'Paralympics is [ADJECTIVE] compared to the Olympics.'

I wonder if there is a word that matched the [ADJECTIVE] in the above sentence.

Comment: *less attention than* would be correct. You could use “less viewership.” But doing a comparative in one word is hard.

Comment: It's likely to be the past tense of a verb being used as an adjective, but what's the reason for wanting something monosyllabic?

Comment: I doubt that a one syllable word exists **To neglect -> neglected** - to give/pay little attention to something or someone.

Comment: *Often ignored, slighted, unloved, skipped over, under-funded, unfunded* or "given short shrift* would fit well but I can't think of a one-syllable word that would have the right meaning.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no reason to restrict solutions to one syllable without saying why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the past-tense-used-as-adjectives from the verbs in dubious's answer, there's also "shunned".

But all of these carry emotional baggage. If there was no particular reason for the word to be single syllable, it would sound like you were looking for "underreported".

Comment: Good one. [_Lexico_](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shunned) defines the adjective _shunned_ as: "Persistently avoided, ignored, or rejected."

Comment: Also FYI: This type of adjective is called a "past participle adjective"; and they are under "participial adjectives".

Comment: I think the "shunned" sentence is far stronger than what OP was looking for.

Comment: @aparente001 - so do I : that's what I meant by "emotional baggage". Lot of good neutral words out there, but it's trying to shoehorn it into one syllable that's making this difficult.

Answer (score -1):

The following verbs, although not exact matches, are single-syllable (but not when put in your sentence):

- [shirk](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/shirk)
- [skip](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/skip)
- [skimp](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/skimp)
- [spurn](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/spurn)
- [scorn](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scorn)

Comment: Those should work - just add "..ed" to turn them into an adjective and they're still single syllable.

Comment: They don't really have the same meaning, do they? 'Paralympics is shirked compared to the Olympics.' to me suggests less effort put into it rather than less attention paid, Paralympics is scorned compared to the Olympics.' would make me think it received negative rather than positive attention, not 'little'.

Comment: @Spagirl - agreed, though I couldn't think of anything neutral that had one syllable.